# How to use pandas.Grouper to group integers in intervals?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, grouping

Is `pandas.Grouper` only thought to be used for dates? Or can it also be used for integers?

I would like to use `pandas.Grouper` in combination with `pandas.pivot_table`.
Here is an example on how to use `pandas.Grouper` for a column containing `dates`:

```
import pandas
import numpy
from datetime import datetime

date_data_frame = pandas.DataFrame(
            {                
                "date": [
                    datetime(2019, 9, 1, 13, 0),
                    datetime(2019, 9, 1, 13, 5),
                    datetime(2019, 10, 1, 20, 0),
                    datetime(2019, 10, 3, 10, 0),
                    datetime(2019, 12, 2, 12, 0),
                    datetime(2019, 9, 2, 14, 0),
                ],
                "name": "Maria Maria Maria Maria Jane Carlos".split(),
                "value": [25, 9, 4, 3, 2, 8],
            }
        )

grouped_pivot_table = pandas.pivot_table(
    date_data_frame,
    index=[pandas.Grouper(key="date", freq="M")], #grouped entries to show as row headers
    columns='name',               #entries to show as column headers
    values='value',               #entries to aggregate and show as cells
    aggfunc=numpy.sum,            #aggregation function(s)
)

print(grouped_pivot_table)
```

Now lets assume **I do not have dates**, but integers between 1 and 100 and I would like to group them in intervals of 10 (1-10, 11-20, ...).
How can I specify the intervals for the grouping using `pandas.Grouper`?

I tried freq="10" but that did not work:

```
import pandas
import numpy
from datetime import datetime
    
date_data_frame = pandas.DataFrame(
            {                
                "param": [
                    1,
                    5,
                    10,
                    15,
                    22,
                    33,
                ],
                "name": "Maria Maria Maria Maria Jane Carlos".split(),
                "value": [25, 9, 4, 3, 2, 8],
            }
)
    
grouped_pivot_table = pandas.pivot_table(
    date_data_frame,
    index=[pandas.Grouper(key="param", freq="10")], #grouped entries to show as row headers
    columns='name',               #entries to show as column headers
    values='value',               #entries to aggregate and show as cells
    aggfunc=numpy.sum,            #aggregation function(s)
)
    
print(grouped_pivot_table)
```

If that is not possible with `pandas.Grouper` what should I use instead to group the param index of my pivot table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible idea is use integer division, I think `Grouper` working only with datetimes:

```
grouped_pivot_table = pandas.pivot_table(
    date_data_frame,
    index= (date_data_frame["param"] - 1) // 10, #grouped entries to show as row headers
    columns='name',               #entries to show as column headers
    values='value',               #entries to aggregate and show as cells
    aggfunc=numpy.sum,            #aggregation function(s)
)
    
print(grouped_pivot_table)
name   Carlos  Jane  Maria
param                     
0         NaN   NaN   34.0
1         NaN   NaN    7.0
2         NaN   2.0    NaN
3         8.0   NaN    NaN
```

Or use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with closing interval from right side:

```
bins = range(0, date_data_frame["param"].max() // 10 * 10 + 20, 10)
labels = ['{}-{}'.format(i + 1, j) for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])]

grouped_pivot_table = pandas.pivot_table(
    date_data_frame,
    #grouped entries to show as row headers
    index= pd.cut(date_data_frame["param"], bins=bins, labels=labels), 
    columns='name',               #entries to show as column headers
    values='value',               #entries to aggregate and show as cells
    aggfunc=numpy.sum,            #aggregation function(s)
)
    
print(grouped_pivot_table)
name   Carlos  Jane  Maria
param                     
1-10      NaN   NaN   38.0
11-20     NaN   NaN    3.0
21-30     NaN   2.0    NaN
31-40     8.0   NaN    NaN
```

or not (`right=False` parameter):

```
bins = range(0, date_data_frame["param"].max() // 10 * 10 + 20, 10)
labels = ['{}-{}'.format(i + 1, j) for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])]

grouped_pivot_table = pandas.pivot_table(
    date_data_frame,
    #grouped entries to show as row headers
    index= pd.cut(date_data_frame["param"], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False), 
    columns='name',               #entries to show as column headers
    values='value',               #entries to aggregate and show as cells
    aggfunc=numpy.sum,            #aggregation function(s)
)
    
print(grouped_pivot_table)
name   Carlos  Jane  Maria
param                     
1-10      NaN   NaN   34.0
11-20     NaN   NaN    7.0
21-30     NaN   2.0    NaN
31-40     8.0   NaN    NaN
```